# Let $a_n$ be a convergent sequence. Prove that if $a_n\geq a$ for $a_n$ but finitely many $n$, then $\lim a_n\geq a$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I have tried proving this by contradiction 
Suppose $\lim a_n<a$ and $a_n\geq a$ for all but finitely many $n$.
Let $A=\lim a_n$ and $\varepsilon =a-A$.
By definition $| a_n-A | <\varepsilon$ which simplifies to $a_n<a$.
Does it work? Could you check it for me please.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Yes it suffices. :) Better to explain a little bit about what happened in the "simplifies to" passage. You could add something like $a_{n} - A \leq |a_{n}-A| < \varepsilon = a-A$. Note that if you are writing these for someone other than you to read, then you want to convince the reader that you are in total understanding of the stuff instead of assuming so-and-so is trivial so I don't have to detail it :).

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea. Suppose $A=\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n$ and $a_n\geq a$ for all but finitely many $n$, but $A<a$.

Then $a-A>0$, so by def'n of a limit we have, for all but finitely many $n$, that  $|a_n-A|<a-A.$

But $|a_n-A|<a-A\implies a_n<A+(a-A)=a,$ which only holds for finitely many $n.$

Writing all the details  is not just for style. You can confirm that you are right when you think you are.